# adding a valid check image or icon over an image in a label

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have 5 radio type inputs, I associated an image that contains a picture in big entries are hidden and the image and clickable (handle this in JS).

now we have a click on a click on a valid image check (fa -fa-check by example) over I made a function or I can put an outline around the images once but impossible to put an image over is staggering or I'm doing it wrong.

Thank you for your help.

```
                    /*-----twig-html---*/

                   <div class="col-6">

                        <div class="label-div" style="width: 450px;">
                            {% for i in 1..10 %}

                            <label for="scale{{question.id}}for{{i}}" style="margin:3px;"><img src="{{asset('images/survey/'~ i ~'.jpg')}}"></label>
                            <input type="radio" class="radio-pict" name="{{question.id}}"id="scale{{question.id}}for{{i}}" value="{{i}}">

                            {% endfor %}

                        </div>

                    </div>

                     /*----jquery/js----*/
           $('.label-div [type="radio"]').click('change', function () {
               $(this)
                  .prev().addClass('selected')
                  .siblings().removeClass('selected');
            });

                     /*------CSS-------*/

          .selected{
             outline: outset #84898b;
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's ok for this problem  i just use fontawesome on css